# Can I rely on sddocname being indexed?

Tags: vespa

Cannot find in your documentation anywhere wheter "sddocname" is automatically indexed , and therefore I can fully rely on the best possible performance when querying by sddocname. Thank you for answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sddocname is indexed. The &model.restrict api (http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/search-api-reference.html#model.restrict) uses sddocname internally.